# D3 barplot only using half my data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a d3.js barplot using some json data containing 12 elements. The data value I'm using for bar height is fpkm.  I'm able to return that value as a callback to d3's data function- but only for half the elements.

My problem is that only the first half of the values are appearing in my barplot. I only get 6 rows corresponding to my first 6 values.

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Mvt/

I can't seem to figure out why it's only using half the elements in my json.

Any help = appreciated.

html:

```
<div align='center' id="GECGplot" style='width:98%;text-align:center;'></plot>
```

and the js:

```
var gecgData= {"nodeName":"GECG","children":[{"nodeName":0,"nodeData":{"id":"643139","library_id":"SI_5589","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"1.1241","fpkm_conf_lo":"0.898502","fpkm_conf_hi":"1.34969","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"8.33","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":1,"nodeData":{"id":"872561","library_id":"SI_5596","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"1.12666","fpkm_conf_lo":"0.871059","fpkm_conf_hi":"1.38226","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"16.67","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":2,"nodeData":{"id":"1031623","library_id":"SI_5553","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"1.21305","fpkm_conf_lo":"0.949369","fpkm_conf_hi":"1.47674","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"25.00","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":3,"nodeData":{"id":"248423","library_id":"SI_5486","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"1.98203","fpkm_conf_lo":"1.64888","fpkm_conf_hi":"2.31519","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"33.33","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":4,"nodeData":{"id":"1039674","library_id":"SI_5554","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"2.24514","fpkm_conf_lo":"1.83333","fpkm_conf_hi":"2.65696","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"41.67","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":5,"nodeData":{"id":"304849","library_id":"SI_5485","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"2.29868","fpkm_conf_lo":"2.02514","fpkm_conf_hi":"2.57221","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"50.00","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":6,"nodeData":{"id":"417495","library_id":"SI_5484","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"2.61196","fpkm_conf_lo":"2.28949","fpkm_conf_hi":"2.93442","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"58.33","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":7,"nodeData":{"id":"928522","library_id":"SI_5595","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"2.94397","fpkm_conf_lo":"2.61962","fpkm_conf_hi":"3.26832","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"66.67","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":8,"nodeData":{"id":"622876","library_id":"SI_5552","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"3.27303","fpkm_conf_lo":"2.79509","fpkm_conf_hi":"3.75097","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"75.00","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":9,"nodeData":{"id":"50230","library_id":"SI_5487","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"9.88611","fpkm_conf_lo":"8.6495","fpkm_conf_hi":"11.1227","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"83.33","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":10,"nodeData":{"id":"816444","library_id":"SI_5594","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"15.1868","fpkm_conf_lo":"13.8218","fpkm_conf_hi":"16.5519","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"91.67","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}},

{"nodeName":11,"nodeData":{"id":"496931","library_id":"SI_5551","gene_id":"ENSG00000157554","gene_short_name":"ERG","fpkm":"52.249","fpkm_conf_lo":"50.8217","fpkm_conf_hi":"53.6763","fpkm_status":"OK","fpkm_percentile_compendium":"100.00","chr_id":"21","start":"39751948","end":"40033704","locus":"21:39751948-40033704","report":"0","tracking_id":null,"class_code":null,"nearest_ref":null,"tss_id":null,"length":null,"coverage":null,"fpkm_percentile_origin_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_collection_tissue":null,"fpkm_percentile_sample_cancer":null,"fpkm_fold_change_benign":null}}]}
    ;



//Width and height
// var w = $('#GECGplot').width();
var w = 700;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 1; 
var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10};

var xScale = d3.scale.linear().
  domain([0, 20]). // your data minimum and maximum
  range([0, h]); // the pixels to map to, e.g., the width of the diagram.


//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#GECGplot")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
   // .data(dataset)
   .data(function(d, i) {
        return plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm;
    })
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        // alert(plotData.length);
        return i * (w / plotData.length);
    })
   .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        alert(plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm);
        return h - (plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm * 50);  //Height minus data value
    })
   .attr("width", w / plotData.length - barPadding)
   .attr("height", function(d, i) {
        return plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm * 50;  //Just the data value
    })
   .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return "rgb(0, 0, " + (plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm * 50) + ")";
    })

    svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(function(d, i) {
        return plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / plotData.length) + (w / plotData.length - barPadding) / 2;
    })
     .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return h - (plotData[i].nodeData.fpkm * 50) + 14; 
    })
    // alert(tableSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. You bind the array "children" to the rectangle elements so you dont need the argument 'i' to access the value you need.

Also, I would recommend using the d3.scale.ordinal() for your x axis as opposed to calculating it explicitly from the data. Litte more flexible.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cef4D/

```
 svg.selectAll("rect")
     .data(plotData)
   .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i * (w / plotData.length);})
     .attr("y", function(d) {
       return h - (d.nodeData.fpkm * 50);  //Height minus data value
     })
     .attr("width", w / plotData.length - barPadding)
     .attr("height", function(d, i) {
       return d.nodeData.fpkm * 50;  //Just the data value
     })
     .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
       return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.nodeData.fpkm * 50) + ")";
     })
```

Comment: + 1 zillion.  I am planning to scale the range. Will check out scale.ordinal(). Thanks